# Form_for in an index rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My project is about an online Shopping site.Now i'm tring to create Basket.
I have an error when i try to edit Basket.
My code is :

```
<% @basket.each do |t|%>
<tr>
<td>
    <%= form_for [:editnum,t], url: user_basket_path(current_user,t) do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :Number%>
        <%= f.number_field :num %>
        <%= f.submit :Edit %>
    <%end%>
</td>
```

And in the Controller I try to get the params:

```
params.require(:editnum).permit(:num)
```

But the error is :

```
param is missing or the value is empty: editnum
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be...

```
params.require(:basket).permit(:num)
```

---

The error is from the [params hash](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters), stating that `editnum` does not exist. Your params method is *requiring* the `editnum` value, hence you should be passing the following params hash:

```
params: {
   "editnum" => {
      "num" => "value"
   }
}
```

The strong params method will essentially "require" `editnum`, and if it doesn't get it, will reject the request & raise an exception (your error).

The way around this is to make sure you're passing the correct values.

Since you're using `form_for`, you should expect the "top level" params hash to be the *object* you're editing. In your case, it is a `basket`, so I would expect a `basket` value to be present:

```
params: {
   "basket" => {
      "num" => "value"
   }
}
```

--

I think you're getting confused with how you're calling nested data. Just because you're nesting your routes / resources under `editnum` doesn't mean your data structure will have to conform to it.

Comment: OK! Can you tell me why it should be :basket

Comment: Sure, give me a minute and I'll write it for you

Comment: Nice! You should mark it as correct as to avoid confusion for others